# Where did tabbed controller views go in storyboard?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Forgive but I haven't coded in about a year or two, so I haven't been following the latest update in Xcode.

Anyways, I decided to go back and brush up on some skills and I noticed right off the bat that a lot has changed.
I created a new project using the tabbed view controller set up, usually it shows in storyboard immediately upon creating the project. Now there is nothing there. Where did it go and how do I bring it back?

I attached a screenshot so you can see the simulator running the tabbed apps but not showing in storyboard.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byc1P.png)

Comment: I noticed this is the launch.storyboard... I just saw “storyboard”... it looks like the update got rid of the main one. Maybe it has something to do with the difference between swiftUI and storyboard when setting up the options in the beginning... i’ll do some more research into it. It seems like SwiftUI is a new thing.

Answer (score 2):

You opened the LaunchScreen.storyboard. This layout appears on the screen for a few moments while the app is launching.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/responding_to_the_launch_of_your_app
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/launch-screen

The storyboard that you are looking for is **Main.storyboard**

Notice, that there is no **Main.storyboard** if you start with SwiftUI

Answer (score 0):

There are no specialized app templates any more. But there is still a tab view controller object in the storyboard editor's library, so just drag it into the canvas and use it. It gives you same two-child tab view controller as before.